# Using A WCF Service To Pass An Instantiated Class

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, service

I've got a C# class library with approximately 50 classes with hundreds of properties. It can take a while to instantiate my classes, so as an optimization I was considering having them instantiated on a server and then have the server pass the instantiated classes to a client application via a WCF Service.

Seems like it should work fine. However, from what I understand, if I want to do this I would need to not only mark every class as `[DataContract]` but also every property as `[DataMember]`. Is this really true? Seems crazy that this would need to be done, especially on every property. Is there a way to just say the entire class is serializable without having to go through this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `[DataContract]` you'll need to specify the `[DataMember]` for each member too.

Alternatively - mark the class with `[Serializable]` and the serializer will serialize all the  internals for you unless you explicitly say otherwise (`[Serializable]` works on an opt-out approach whereas `[DataContract]` works on an opt-in approach).

However - depending on what, exactly, you are trying to do - this approach may be flawed.

When you pass an object over WCF, you are not really passing the object at all - you are passing a copy of the object. In fact, the original object will be serialized, passed down the wire and deserialized at the other end. This means the client still has to <s>instantiate</s> reconstitute an instance of the class and then populate all the properties. You may gain nothing, and potentially have a rather expensive call with a lot of data being passed across the wire.

So it all depends what you are doing. If you don't mind the clients getting a copy of the instance and if the expense is not due to the sheer amount of data but other things like slow database access, then fine. Otherwise your approach may not buy you anything.

As an aside, in .Net remoting it is possible to have a reference to a remote object (i.e. you client can reference the object on the server) - if the type itself derives from `MarshalByRefObject`, but that is not the case here with WCF - you end up with your own copy locally.

Comment: You're not wrong - the OP probably isn't going to gain anything much in the way of performance. But this doesn't really address his question on decorating classes and properties with attributes for serialization.

Comment: Wait...that doesn't seem right.  So, you're saying that if I have the following code on my client application, the constructor for the object gets called not only on the WCF server but also on the client machine?  Seems to me the client machine should get the instantiated copy without the constructor being called a second time:  MyObject obj = null;  static void WCF_SVC_GetMyObjInstCompleted(object sender, WCF_SVCRef.GetMyObjInstCompletedEventArgs e) { obj = e.Result; }

Comment: I see you just updated your answer.  Ok, so the reason I want to do this is because of slow database access when instantiating the properties and also because of slow initial calcs that have to run when instantiated.  If the class was already populated it would be much quicker for me.  So in this case, I would benefit, right?  Because those won't run a second time.   Oh, and regarding Remoting, I was initially going to approach it this way, but I've been reading that MS is close to deprecating Remoting.  Is this still the case?  Thanks

Comment: @Yuck - yes you're right - I've updated the answer to answer the original question too.

Comment: @RobLevine +1 However, you don't even need to mark up all of the classes and properties in some cases. See my answer for another approach - with caveats explained.

Comment: @Nullqwerty - possibly a bad choice of words on my part - I shouldn't have said "instantiate" as it implies calling the constructor. For `[DataContract]` and `[Serializable]` it doesn't call the constructor but it still has to "rebuild" the instance. If the issue is slow database access as you say, yes - maybe this will be beneficial. I guess - try it and see!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much!  Ok, in this case, I think it'll help mainly because of my calcs and all my linq queries against the objects.  And thanks for the distinction on [Serializable] vs [DataContract].  I wasn't aware and thought [Serializable] was the standard web service way and [DataContract] was the WCF way.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Nullqwerty - my pleasure! In fact - `[Serializable]` is normally related to binary serialization (with the BinaryFormatter) - but when they wrote the DataContractSerializer for WCF they made it support the  `[Serializable]` too.

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to do this, I would need to not only mark every class as
>   [DataContract] but also every property as [DataMember]. Is this really
>   true?

Yes and no.

If the client code can't import the assembly that contains those classes then, yes, you need to mark them up. This is so that WCF can tell clients how to interpret the result sets.

If you can use a common assembly both in the WCF service **and** the clients (e.g. like a POCO library) then you don't need to apply those attributes. WCF will just tell clients to refer to the assembly by it's strong name.

Here's what the WSDL might look like in case #2:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation = "http://localhost:12902/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0"
       namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation = "http://localhost:12902/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1"
       namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation = "http://localhost:12902/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd2"
      namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAssembly.MyProject" />
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Where `MyAssembly.MyProject` above refers to a namespace in your assembly. If you follow the link at `http://localhost:12902/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd2` (on your local machine of course) you'd get an XSD describing the entities serialized within that namespace. You don't have to decorate the class. WCF does all of this for you.

Comment: So is this what you're saying?  I have a class library that produces a dll.  I include the dll into the project for the client application and include the dll into the project for the wcf service.  If I do this, then I won't have to mark either datacontract or datamember on the classes in the class library, but I'll still be able to pass an instantiate class from it over the wcf service?

Comment: @Nullqwerty That's correct. But there are some restrictions. It should be obvious, but this approach only works with the auto-generated client class .NET provides to you when you import a Service Reference using Visual Studio. If you have something other than that consuming the service you have to use the approach where you decorate the classes with attributes. I'll update my answer...

Comment: "this approach only works with the auto-generated client class .NET provides to you when you import a Service Reference using Visual Studio"  ....  Ahhh, ok that makes sense, because I actually had tried this first and I was getting an error on the service call.  But the clients object I was using was of the type from the class library, not from the auto-generated class.  Interesting...I'll have to think about the implications of this approach because the client application is already a mature product and it's fairly large, so there could be a lot to change.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nullqwerty Yep - you'd use something like AutoMapper to bridge the gap. If you can live inside these restrictions WCF really does a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks Yuck!  If I could mark 2 answers as the accepted answer I would, as yours is just as helpful but just a different approach.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. It needs to have the two properties on the classes, structs, fields so that the NET knows to serialize those classes. Without those properties, those won't get serialized and you won't see that field or class in the client.

Answer (score 0):

In a real separate client server scenario you have to. (if you cant share a file.)